# Java Streams Files.lines() throws IOException. Why?

Tags: java, exception, functional-programming, stream

`Files.lines()` returns a `Stream<String>` which, as I understand it, is not evaluated unless I apply a terminal operation on it. Why, then, does it declare an `IOException`. What could go wrong during the initialization of the `Stream` that would justify the exception declaration?

My use case is the method below. I want to create a stream that streams all text lines with a search pattern from all files in a directory.

Now, if `Files.lines()` encounters a file formatted in an unexpected encoding during the stream evaluation, it will fail with a runtime exception. This exception will not be caught by the catch block. Why, then, do I need the exception handling at all?

```
public static Stream<String> grep(Path dir, Pattern pattern) throws IOException {
    return Files.walk(dir)
            .filter(p -> !Files.isDirectory(p) && p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".log"))
            .map(p -> {
                try {
                    return Files.lines(p);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    return Stream.<String>empty();
                }
            }).flatMap(s -> s)
            .filter(l -> pattern.matcher(l).find());
}
```

Comment: After doing some experiments, I see that the file is being opened already at stream initialization, so the exception will be thrown directly at calling Files::lines().

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is something that can be answered by simply reading the freely available source code.

Comment: That may be obvious in the source code, but the API appears counter intuitive considering the lazy evaluation nature of streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while the stream that is returned is not evaluated until a terminal operation is applied the creation of the stream itself within Files.lines is creating a new Files.newBufferedReader which could throw the given exception.

We can see this on line 3744 - [source](http://atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/openjdk/jdk/8u92/src-html/java/nio/file/Files.html).

```
public static Stream<String> lines(Path path, Charset cs) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path, cs); // this could throw IOException
    try {
        return br.lines().onClose(asUncheckedRunnable(br));
    } catch (Error|RuntimeException e) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            try {
                e.addSuppressed(ex);
            } catch (Throwable ignore) {}
        }
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok ,that makes sense. Is there a way to prevent the stream in my method from breaking in case the actual reading causes problems?

Comment: If the data set is small then using Files::readAllLines with exception handling in the map would be the easiest solution.

If the data set is larger then you should be able to perform some wrapping to swallow the exception but this gets a bit more tricky.

Are you planning to use serial or parallel Streams?